# VBA Center Across Selection Hotkey

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a hotkey shortcut for the "Center Across Selection" functionality.  The "Merge Cells" functionality looks nice and all, but is horrid to use in practice because of the problems it creates with Macros and such.  So, naturally, center across selection is the go-to tool.  I use the keyboard to navigate in Excel, so it would be very nice to have a custom shortcut to make this selection easier and faster, since it is used often.

I have some code for this, which I believe should work, but for some reason, it is not:

In PERSONAL.XLSB - Module 1

```
Private Sub WorkBook_Open()

Application.OnKey "^q", "center_across_selection"

End Sub
```

In PERSONAL.XLSB - Module 3

```
Sub center_across_selection()

    With Selection
        'converts centered text to regular format
        If .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection Then
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        'converts regular text to centered across selection
        Else
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Then, once I save this, exit out of the workbook (and all other workbooks as well), reopen the workbook, and try to use the `Ctrl+Q` shortcut, nothing happens to my cells!  Please help me find where I am going wrong.

Comment: How is it not working? What is it doing instead if anything?

Comment: Literally nothing at all.  Nothing happens when I press `Ctrl+q`.  For example, if I add "abc" to `A1`, then select `A1:A2`, and press `Ctrl+q`, nothing happens.  No errors, but also no center across cells functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Private Sub WorkBook_Open()` from *MODULE 1* to the workbook code area.

Comment: Brilliant.  I knew it would be an easy fix.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You've implemented the macro in a standard module; `Workbook_Open` means to handle the `Workbook` object's `Open` event, but a standard module doesn't do that (the `ThisWorkbook` class/Excel object module does, as shown in [Gary's (well, his student's anyway) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017164/1188513)).

So either you move the macro to `ThisWorkbook`'s code-behind, or you rename the macro to Excel4-compatible `Auto_Open`:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^q", "center_across_selection"
End Sub
```

Note that this `Auto_Open` macro will run regardless of the state of `Application.EnableEvants` when the workbook is opened.

Comment: I do appreciate the explanation of why I was incorrect.  I used @Gary's Student 's answer for this question.  However, I will keep the `Auto_Open()` sub in mind for the future.